in Swift I receive crashes from users about an optional that is nil trying to unwrap it, but the variable in question is not optional. Any clues?
I receive, always in the same spot in my code, this classic message:

The problem is, the variable is not declared as an optional. This is the corresponding code:
func idealScalebarPositionInPixels() -> Double {
   
        var distance: Double = 0.0
        
        let distanceBetweenViewsCenters = self.mainViewController.measureButton.center.y - self.mainViewController.compassView.center.y
        if Device().isPad {
            distance = self.mainViewController.compassView.center.y + (distanceBetweenViewsCenters / 4)
            distance *= UIScreen.main.scale
        } else {
            distance = self.mainViewController.compassView.center.y + (distanceBetweenViewsCenters / 2)
            distance *= (UIScreen.main.scale / 2)
        }
        if self.framework.navigating {
            distance = distance + 125
        }
        if Device.current.isPad {
            distance = distance - 24
        }
        
        return distance
        
    
}

I receive the same reports from firebase and Xcode, and I am certain the bug refers to the "distance" variable, which, as you can see, is not an optional. How this can be possible ? thanks a lot for your attention.

"I am certain the bug refers to the "distance" variable" Are you sure?

Xcode reports the error to be on the line "return distance"

But nothing is being unwrapped at that line and distance is not an optional. Maybe you need to look into your other properties like mainViewController and the properties accessed from that type.

You get the „…implicitly unwrapped…“ message, not „unexpectedly found nil“. Yes, nothing is force unwrapped, but look for some property declared with ! that you are using before it is initialized.

@AlfonsoTesauro Clearly the system isn't behaving in a way that matches with your certain understanding of it, so I'd suggest really dropping any assumptions and investigating it with a fresh mind.

Unrelated, but is if Device().isPad the same as if Device.current.isPad?

I guess that compassView, and measureButtons are IBOutlets, which are marked with a !, and they are nil for some reason... And the force unwrap is on their declaration, not on your code, hence why you don't see a force unwrap on the code you've shown. There are different reasons why an IBOulet is nil (no link between Storyboard or Xib and Code, or wrong initialization making it not load the Storyboard/Xib attached with it, so the connection is nil)

I agree with @Larme. Possibly the code is called before the compassView and/or measureButtons are allocated. This might happen for instance if this function is called from a didSet closure. If for instance you initiate the ViewController, and then do viewController.myVariable = 12 ... and only after that you present the viewController, you can be sure that the views inside have not been allocated yet when this function is called from the didSet of this variable.

Others have mentioned this obliquely, but let me explain the issue clearly:
Swift has a rather nasty type called "implicitly unwrapped optional". It might look like this:
@IBOutlet var measureButton: UIButton!

The exclamation point at the end tells the compiler "make this variable an optional, but always quietly unwrap it when I reference it. I know it'll never be nil. If it is nil, crash even though the offending code looks good."
Think of this as a "crash if nil" type, because that's what it does. By default, Interface Builder sets up outlets as implicitly wrapped optionals. It does have the "advantage" that if you have any broken IBOutlet links, your app immediately crashes when you reference the outlet, so it draws your attention to the broken link and you know to go fix it.
That is almost certainly what's going on here. If you want our help diagnosing the exact error you'll need to post the exact line that is crashing and the exact error message it's giving. You may also have to post a screenshot of your storyboard/nibfile, with the "connections inspector" shown.
As others have said, there are more obscure cases like a didSet block where your code might be invoked before your view is loaded and the outlets are set, but that's less common than a broken outlet.

Thanks Duncan, The new version that circumvents the error is online now, let's cross fingers :)
